# How is the Hanbury-Brown and Twiss effect used to measure the size of stars?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observational-astronomy, interferometry, instrument

I understand what an [Hanbury Brown and Twiss](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanbury_Brown_and_Twiss_effect) (HBT) interferometer *does*, but how can this be used to measure the apparent angular diameter of some object?

What is the mathematical explaination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An HBTI works in a very similar manner to a [Fizeau](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fizeau_experiment) / [Michelson stellar interferometer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson_stellar_interferometer). But in an HBTI, a correlation is made between fluctuations of amplitude (intensity) at points across a surface, unlike a Fizeau/Michelson which correlates fluctuations in phase. The timing of these fluctuations is much longer and this leads to a much larger tolerance in path length differences than with phase interferometers.

It can be shown<sup>[1][2]</sup> that the visibility $V$ at a baseline $d$ is equal to:
$$V^{2}=\gamma^{2}= \frac{\langle I_1 * I_2 \rangle}{\langle I_1 \rangle \langle I_2 \rangle}$$

Where $I_1$ and $I_2$ are the measurements at two separated detectors, and the angle brackets indicate time averages.

<sup>[1] The Intensity Interferometer, Hanbury Brown.</sup>
  <sup>[2] Optical Stellar Interferometry, Labeyrie.</sup>

Answer (score 5):

A good (non mathematical) explanation I found on this is here:
http://www.2physics.com/2010/11/hanbury-brown-and-twiss-interferometry.html

Comment: Welcome to Astronomy! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.