# What's a simple experiment to perform, near the equator, to show the rotation of the earth?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

Since Foucaults pendulum works poorly or not at all near the equator, what other simple experiment could be performed to demonstrate the rotation of the earth?

Comment: The Eötvös effect

Comment: You could observe that the sun's position in the sky changes with time.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66234/2451 excluding Foucault pendulum.